# Does "prosody" include facial-expressions and gestures?

Tags: meaning

Is ["prosody"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosody_%28linguistics%29) purely aural / auditory or can it also include visual perceptions?

Are facial-expressions (rolling of eyes to indicate sarcasm) considered as contributing to *prosody*?

What about hand-gestures like [air quotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_quotes)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Prosody** refers specifically to audible qualities of speech.  The roots of the word are in song and tone and accent of a syllable.  The other things you speak of are forms of *non-verbal communication*.

Comment: The non-linguistic parts of communication, such as gesture, facial expression, etc., are usually grouped under the term 'pragmatics'. The term 'non-verbal communication' could refer to sign languages, which are complete linguistic systems and not part of pragmatics.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut, I think you should make your comment an answer.

Comment: @JLG Actually I was wondering if it should be migrated to the Linguistics SE?